# React fetch call for cross domain throws 404 error

Tags: javascript, c#, reactjs, cors, asp.net-web-api2

I am working on react application which makes cross domain API calls. I had configured in server like below

```
<httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="https://example.site.com" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="POST, PUT, DELETE, GET, OPTIONS" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="content-Type, accept, origin, X-Requested-With, Authorization, name" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" value="true" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
```

React UI Code below

```
fetch(url, {
            body,
            credentials: 'include',
            headers,
            method

        }).then(response => response.json()).then((responseContent: any) => {



            return responseContent;
        })
```

But still am getting CORS origin issue  like we are not able to access the resource as per the CORS policy.

Above one is working fine chrome incognito window.only it is throwing error normal chrome browser.

If i remove "credentials: 'include'" ,CORS issue not coming but  throwing HTTP 302 status with redirect issue.

**tried other ways like below:(but no luck)**

1. Removed web.config entry and used UseCors option in startup.cs file.
2. Removed UseCors option and tried EnableCors in Webapiconfig with corresponding parameters.

**Error Screenshot below:**

[image]

Comment: what domain is your react code running? localhost?

Comment: @VaibhavSingh no that is running in example.site.com and trying to access the service in apiservice.site.com

Comment: <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="https://example.com" />

Comment: this issue is here, you need to add the correct domain here

Comment: nope that is not the case . just i provided you the sample  code above.. I edited my question with correct domain

Comment: Can you share the screenshot of the error from the console?

Comment: @VaibhavSingh updated the screenshot

Comment: It is a CORS issue only, you can't share the exact domain name here but on your server, you need to set the second domain in the screenshot.